# Ajax JSON request always sends none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I'm creating a very simple demo web app. All I want is to press the button and have the message go from the front to back end, and then pass back to front end. Nothing fancy.

I'm having trouble getting "data1" (in JS) accessible in Pyhton/Flask. I'm not sure if the issue is with how I send it from JS or how I access it in Python. Based off of other questions I've read, I seem to be doing it correctly. In JS I send using `data : JSON.stringify(data1)`, and in python I access using `data = request.json`. So what is wrong here?

I have tried accessing it using request.json, request.get_json(), and tried doing it without JSON, be just sending "data", and accessing it via  request.form.get('word'). But none of these seem to work.

Cmd Line Output:

```
xxxxxx@ezri:~/Desktop/flaskwebapp$ python webapp_starter.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 276-649-445
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2017 10:48:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/examplemethod' [POST]>
data None
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2017 10:48:54] "POST /examplemethod HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/castro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

This error is clearly because data is always assigned `None` by the assignment in flask using request.json. So the real error seems to be in properly getting the data from JS to Python.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
<p>a paragraph of text bla bla bla</p>
<button id="btn"> CLICK ME! </button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
"use strict";

console.log("On load");

var main = function() {
    var run_method = function(){

      var data1 = {"word":"hello"}
      console.log("Before " + data1);
      $.ajax({
          url : "/examplemethod",
          type : "POST",
          data : JSON.stringify(data1),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',

      })
      .done(function(data){
          // Parse out image info
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(data);

      });
    }

    $("#btn").on("click",function(){
        //event.preventDefault();
          run_method()
    })
}



$(document).ready(main);
```

**Python/Flask:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

#Init flask server
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def initialize():
    '''
    Initialize the page

    IN: None
    OUT: None (loads page)
    '''
    #render page from html
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/examplemethod", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example_method():
    global data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request
        data = request.json
        #request.form.get('word')
        print "data", data
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=int("8000"), debug=True)
```

Comment: try sending data without stringify

Comment: I did, and used request.form.get('word') to access it, as I said that also did not work.

Comment: Priyesh meant to send data without stringify and yet access it from flask as `request.json`, I think jquery's `ajax` calls stringify internally

Comment: by the way are you sure that `data` needs to be global ?

Comment: Just tried that (and I'm pretty sure I have done so before). Same exact result. I am fairly certain it should be global (That's how I've done it in previous flask apps), but commenting that out did not change anything. I have also been getting a 500 Error in the browser's console, if that's at all helpful.

Comment: I have created the following jfiddle that you can use to verify that the javascript is sending the expected json with a POST request: https://jsfiddle.net/2m5nbwbm/1/
Still not clear why you cannot read it in python.

Comment: I've used JSFiddle, but not sure how to verify a POST request is working using it. And I have no idea why I cannot read it in python either...

Answer (score 1):

Try `get_json(force=True)`. It forces and convert data into json(dict) format. There might be a chance that browser is not sending correct content type, as then `.json` fails but `get_json` gives correct result.

You can check headers using `request.headers`.

I just tried you code, and I got following results

1. With `request.json`

   `{'word': 'hello'}`
2. With `request.form`

   `ImmutableMultiDict([])`
3. `get_json(force=True)`

   `{'word': 'hello'}`

Also [docs](https://flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.json) says

> The get_json() method should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

In $.ajax calls, the data options must be either an object, query string, or array. JSON strings won't work. So just replace 'JSON.stringify(data1)' with data1.

On the Flask side it looks like you need to access the request information sent by POST method by using request.form['word'], and from GET method, request.args.get('word'). Also, do the method and route need to match? '/examplemethod' and 'def examplemethod' for instance? I'm not familiar with Flask's naming conventions:

```
#At top of file
from Flask import jsonify

@app.route("/examplemethod", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example_method():
    global data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request
        data = request.form['word']
        print "POST", data
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        print request
        data = request.args.get('word')
        print "GET", data
    return jsonify(data)
```

You also may need to use jsonify function in Flask. See documentation for using jQuery with Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/

Comment: It is not a requirement for them to be the same (theres an underscore so they are not actually the same). It is just a convention, or really more of a personal preference.

As for your solution, I tried to implemented, messed something up, and then in trying to fix that got it to work in the way I originally wrote it, but I have no idea how or why... so... thank you?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

I'm honestly not 100% sure what I did to fix it. I'm compared my code in a difference checker to what I posted above, but found that all of the changes are either print statements, or use/modify the data AFTER a sucessful request, so no idea these changes fixed it.

I invite anyone else to try and figure out what changed.

JS

```
var run_method = function(){

  var data1 = {"word":"hello"}
  console.log("Before " + data1["word"]);
  $.ajax({
      url : "/examplemethod",
      type : "POST",
      data : JSON.stringify(data1),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',

  })
  .done(function(data){
      console.log("After " +data["word"]);
  });
}
```

Python

```
@app.route("/examplemethod", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example_method():
    global data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "POST REQ:", request
        data = request.json
        print "data", data

    data["word"] = "goodbye!"
    return JSONEncoder().encode(data)
```